# How to add context methods to an object

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm making a library for math graphing in canvas, and before, my approach was to directly add methods to the global context prototype, as such

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.point=function(x,y){
    this.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
};
```

However, I found out that that was not recommended, so what I'm trying now is to make a global object, as such

```
window.Graph=function(context){
    this.ctx=context;
    alert(this.ctx);
    this.CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.point=function(x,y){
        this.ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
    };
};
```

I have also tried

```
this.ctx.prototype.point=function(x,y){
        this.ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
};
```

All of them return errors like `cannot set property 'point' to undefined`

The ideal way to call it would be

```
var g=new Graph(ctx);
g.point(5,5);
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Like Jquery? That what you want?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Jquery, but I could learn it, so preferrably Javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you are looking for:

```
function Graph(context) {
    this.context = context;
}

Graph.prototype.point = function (x, y) {
    this.context.fillRect(x, y ,1, 1);
}

var g = new Graph(context);
g.point(5, 5);
```

Answer (score 2):

plalx shows a great design pattern...

Here's just another with a constructor:

```
var Graph = (function () {

    // constructor
    function Graph(context) {

        // "class" properties go here
        this.context = context;
    }

    // "class" methods added to prototype here
    Graph.prototype.point = function (x,y) {
        this.context.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
    };

    // return a self reference
    return Graph;

})();    // make class available by self-executing

// instantiate your Graph class into a graph object
var graph = new Graph(context);
```